# Sample use of a C# Destructor

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, destructor

I'm reading about destructors in C# but I'm having trouble finding a decent use-case for it.

Could someone provide an example of usage with an explanation?

Much, much appreciated.

**Update**
The code sample in the book implements both a Desctuctor and a Dispose() method, see this code snippet from the book.

```
class MyClass
{
    bool disposed = false; // Disposal status
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed == false)
        {
            if (disposing == true)
            {
                // Dispose the managed resources. Factored Dispose

            }
            // Dispose the unmanaged resources.

        }
        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Marko

Comment: http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167/0/page/2 Pretty good article...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finalizers are *very* rarely needed now. They *used* to be required when you had direct access to native resources - but now you should usually be using [`SafeHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) instead.

Joe Duffy has an [excellent post about this](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=86c71425-57bc-4fcb-b34b-3262812f12cf) which goes into rather more details than I would be able to write myself - so go read it :)

A quick note on terminology: the ECMA version of the C# spec refers to them as finalizers; the Microsoft version of the spec has always referred to them as destructors and continues to do so.

Comment: Where are you now? On the train? =P I read your schedule posted on Meta. I have laughed a lot while you were getting upvotes for your schedule! Hehehe... Nah, I have to consider the time zone, so you must be home, not watching TV, but posting on SO! =P Anyway! Have a good evening! =)

Comment: @Will: Alternating between posting and playing PixelJunk Monsters :)

Comment: what a brilliant article - thanks! Glad to see I will rarely need to use it thanks to the implementation of SafeHandle.

Comment: This Jon, always the right word where it fits! I have no other choice than to upvote this answer, even if Jon doesn't need anymore reputation points (kidding here)! =P Hehehe... Keep up the good work Jon! We all need your excellent work!

Comment: @JonSkeet How relevant is this answer when we have destructors. Am reading about C# exam and would like to know difference between the two. I was made to believe Destructor can be used to free unmanaged resources but now your answer suggests otherwise

Comment: @codingbiz: It's relevant because the question was asking when finalizers/destructors are a good idea - and the answer is that these days, that's almost never. Not sure what you mean by "difference between the two" - within C#, finalizer and destructor are synonyms.

Comment: Ok. What you meant by your comment is that Destructors should be preferred? Difference between: Destructor/Finalizer vs SafeHandle. Thanks

Comment: @codingbiz: No, I think my answer is fairly clear that SafeHandle means you should very rarely use destructors...

Answer (score 2):

They're finalizers, not destructors. They're often used to clean up unmanaged resources - if you wrote your own file class, then you would need to use the finalizer to clean up the native file handle.

Comment: `Although there has sometimes been a question as to whether desscturctors should be called "destructors" or "finalizers", the C# Language Specification, Version 3.0, released at the end of 2007, calls this method a destructor.` - Apress Illustrated C# 2008. Has that changed since? Also, some example code would be fantastic!

Comment: Ok, ignore my example code comment, it looks like there's very rarely use for it!

Answer (score 1):

Finalizers are rarely needed in C# and adding one can cause the garbage collector to take longer to clean up the garbage as an extra pass is required to run the finalizer. Instead you should normally use the IDisposable pattern.

An example usage of a finalizer is if you suspect resource leakage you can use it when debugging to check if `Dispose` has been called correctly before the object is garbage collected. If an object that holds unmanaged resources has its finalizer called before Dispose has been called it could be a sign of a resource leakage. But since the finalizer may not ever be called it should not contain any application critical logic.

Comment: Interesting enough the code from the book I'm reading implements both the Dispose and the Destructor (which actually calls `Dispose(false)`).

Comment: @Marko That pattern was common before the introduction of `SafeHandle`s in .net 2.0. It's deprecated now.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I've added the sample code from the book as reference :)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by `destructor`? C# has

- The [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) pattern which you'd use for deterministic destruction
  Useful to close Handles when you don't need them anymore. So they are closed *now* and not whenever the GC decides to collect the object which might be much later or not at all.
  Or in pure managed code to tell an object to remove itself from the object graph, unsubscribe from events,...
  Commonly used with a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement
- The Finalizer which is almost useless. It runs at an unknown time, it might not run at all,...
  The only thing I use it for is to remind me that I forgot to call Dispose on something
  While it has the syntax of a C++ destructor I don't consider it the equivalent of a C++ destructor. I prefer to think about `Dispose()` as the destructor.
- [Critical finalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh21e17c.aspx) and [`SafeHandle`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) which you use for native resources

I think instead of the pattern you posted modern code should own a private SafeHandle and call it's `Dispose` method in it's own Dispose.

Answer (score 0):

The [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface provides a method to use as a destructor/finalzer.

What I mean is that you may implement the `IDisposable` interface in order to free the resources your object is using. As the others have said, this is not the same thing as a good old destructor, since the `Dispose()` method will not be called directly by yourself, but by the managed code to dispose of your object after a while.

Comment: I'm okay with downvotes, but at least tell me what's wrong so that I can learn from my error, if error there is! Even Mark Byers proposes the use `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: No, they're very different. `Dispose` is called *explicitly* by other code, whereas destructors/finalizers are called by the garbage collector, non-deterministically.

Comment: Hey Will: +1 for you! You got there first.

Comment: @Will: I was busy typing the comment. It takes a non-zero amount of time to do so :) I sympathise with the down-vote-but-no-comment complaint though, as I'm often on the receiving end of it...

Comment: The problem with your answer is that it is worded in such a way as to imply that `IDisposable.Dispose()` is the same thing as a “destructor/finalizer”, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @n8wrl: Thanks so much! I must get faster on typing! That's awesome how fast people can type! Sometimes I come to a question where there's no answer, I'm beginning to type in my answer, then click `Post`, and there is already answers there since 5 minutes! Unbelievable! Hehehe...

Comment: @Jon: But when I implement the `IDisposable` interface, and let's say I'm writing my own `Connection` class with an inner `DbConnection` as a private member. When I will, let's say, `Close` my connection, I might as well give a call to the `Dispose` method so that my `DbConnection` private field is disposed accordingly. Isn't it right?

Comment: @Will: Yes, you should call Dispose in that case... but it's still not the same as a finalizer.

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't have 'destructors' as you're probably thinking about them. With .NET's garbage collector, object collection won't happen right away when your class goes out of scope.

I think what you're more interested in is the IDisposable pattern. That is a deterministic way for you to clean up resources your object uses.

In addition, .NET classes can have 'finalizers' which are executed when an object is collected. It can be used to call dispose if the original caller of your object neglected to.

But, implementing a finalizer in your class queues it up for special processing for GC and might have a performance impact.