# How to perform an operation before object is disposed?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, abstract

Working with C#. I have an abstract class that I use to read/write settings to an xml file. When the class is no longer needed I want to perform one last write operation to the xml file before the class gets disposed. I tried putting this code in a destructor method `~myClass() {}` but it throws an exception saying that the safe handle is closed. I am guessing this means that the class is already disposed or partially disposed. So if the destructor is not the correct place to do this where is the correct place? Do I need to implement IDisposable or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `destructor`s in C#. Please refer to this question's accepted answer from Jon Skeet who explains and provide a good article on the topic.
[`Sample use of a C# Destructor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229209/sample-use-of-a-c-destructor/4229231#4229231)

Besides, perhaps should you consider to implement the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface in your class so that you could perform your manoeuvre.

Comment: I think the MS C# standard calls/called them `destructor`. But the name is misleading since it implies that it should be used where a C++ destructor would be used. And IDisposable corresponds to a C++ destructor better than a finalizer.

Answer (score 2):

There are many threads on finalizers on SO just read a few of them.

The basic point is that you should never rely on finalizers since their execution order is undefined or might not run at all. You should use `IDisposable`for any managed cleanup(your case) and SafeHandles/CriticalFinalization for native resources.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like today you are attempting to write out to the settings file in your object's finalizer using a `SafeHandle` field.  This is not the right approach.

Once the object hits the CLR finalizer thread, all bets are off about other managed resources the object can see.  It's very legal and possible for the `SafeHandle` field to already be finalized and hence invalid by the time the containing class`s finalizer runs.

The standard way to work with a scenario like this is to implement `IDisposable` and use the `Dispose` method (which is intended to be called by user code) to properly dispose of managed resources such as the file.

For example:

```
abstract class MyClass : IDisposable { 

  private SafeFileHandle _handle;

  public void Dispose() { 
    WriteTheFile();
    _handle.Dispose();
  }

}
```

Comment: For what is the finalizer used in this example? There is no reason to assume that `_handle` lives longer than the instance of `MyClass`. So I see no difference to the code which just uses a simple parameterless `Dispose` calling WriteFile and then _handle.Dispose

Comment: @CodeInChaos, there is no advantage here.  I originally thought it had an advantage in a corner scenario but I checked the implementation of `SafeHandle` and it's not what I thought and hence the extra finalizer has no purpose.  I removed it.

Comment: What kind of corner scenario?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I thought `SafeHandle` may have a finalizer which was supressed by the `Dispose` call and hence calling `Dispose` had the potential to remove it from the finalization queue before it ran.  I'm still not 100% sure if this would be an advantage or not after I thought about it further anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have your finalizer give you a chance to write some stuff before the file is closed, you need to ensure that a strong reference to the file will outlive your object.  One way to do this would be to store a strong reference to the file in a static field.  When your object's finalizer runs, you can write the data, close the file, and null out the static field.  Note that if your finalizer fails to null out the field, for whatever reason, the file may be kept open indefinitely.